# create link to folder thats useable with ftp

Tags: command-line, ftp

I created some links to folders in my home dir so i don't have to go down the long path all the time, i used 'ln -s' for this.

I can use them when i log in via ssh but when use ftp it just shows the link as a file and not like a shortcut as intended.

I tried to use just 'ln' but that doesn't seem to work with folders, and using the -d is not permitted.

Is there a way to this so i can also it in an ftp program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ssh and ftp there are different security concepts. SSH uses the permissions of the user logged in. Thus via SSH a remote user can access all files the user can access locally on the machine.

Via FTP however, the access is restricted by folder. Thus you cannot / should not leave the directory through a link, else one could create a link to a file "whereever" on your computer via ftp and access it.

If you need file transfer I encourage you to use scp instead of ftp to copy files. Its fairly easy to use and more secure! E.g. you can use filezilla ftp client also with sftp (means ssh / scp)